# Configuration file to Homebridge not recognised. Wemo Platform plugin + Applescript

Tags: json, applescript, homekit

I have problem with my configuration file. Right now JSONLint says:

```
Error: Parse error on line 9:
    ...},   "description": "Jannen HomeKit”,    
    ---------------------^
    Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got         'undefined'
```

And it seems my formatting have some problems.

```
{
"bridge": {
    "name": "jHomebridge",
    "username": "CC:22:3D:E3:CE:30",
    "port": 51826,
    "pin": "031-45-156"
},

"description": "Jannen HomeKit”,

"accessories": [
    {
        "accessory": "Applescript",
        "name": ”Videon katselu”
        "on": "tell application ’’Chrome’’ to open location ’’www.youtube.fi’’”,
        "off": "tell application ’’Chrome’’ to open location ’’www.youtube.fi’’"
    }
],

"platforms": [
    {
        "platform" : "WeMo Platform",
        "name" : "WeMo Platform"
        "expected_accessories" : "0",
        "timeout" : "25",
        "no_motion_timer": "60",
        "homekit_safe" : "1"
    }
]
```

Comment: It might just be a formatting issue, but some of the quotation marks in your json look wrong.  For example at the end of `"Jannen HomeKit”` and `"tell application ’’Chrome’’ to open location ’’www.youtube.fi’’”`.  I'd suggest replacing those quotation marks with "straight" quotation marks, then see if JSONLint is happy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have an issue with your json structure. This [site](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp) has a pretty simple explanation of what the json structure should be.

But basically this is what is should look like...

```
"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

Your error message is pointing to the issue in your line `"description": "Jannen HomeKit”,`